# Using base math operators with Julia Nullables in julia-0.5

Tags: dataframe, julia, nullable

I am using Dataframes in Julia 0.5.1-pre+2 pulled and built locally from github, and I have also tried the Mac dmg download 0.5 download as well, and I am having trouble understanding how to properly work with nullables and nullable arrays.

```
df = DataFrame(x=rand(20), y=rand(20))

 mean(df[:x])
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching /(::Nullable{Float64}, ::Int64)
```

So this errors seems to be telling me that this operation isn't defined for a Nullable{Float} and Int and simply trying an operation like

```
Nullable(2.) / 1
```

will lead to the same error.

I am confused though from the [documentation](https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for DataFrames though, since it shows operations like:

```
mean(df[1])
median(df[1])

mean(df[:A])
median(df[:A])

df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = randn(4))
colwise(cumsum, df)
```

All of which lead to similar undefined method errors when executed on my machine.

I am not sure if this is either the correct behavior in the current ecosystem or a build/package version issue.

Comment: I don' think the Nullable example should work but the DataFrames one def should.

Comment: I have tried your first example and in my macbook it is working. I have installed Julia with homebrew cask. You might want to try it.

Comment: @merch what version of Julia is that?

Comment: @lbollar, I have installed Julia version 0.5.0

Comment: @merch still fails with cask 0.5 version, so I am wondering if this might be a package issue. Julia 0.4.6 cask version worked fine with the above commands.

Comment: @lbollar have you tried removing ~/.julia before installing the 0.5 version?

Comment: @merch I removed .julia directory and started over again with the cask version and now it works. I don't know enough to understand the problem, but must have been package related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, you had the development (master) version of `DataFrames` installed. One possible way that can happen if you had run `Pkg.develop("DataFrames")` at some point.

`DataFrames` is going through a major rewrite, and hence many things may not work correctly on the development version. The release versions should work correctly. Deleting your `.julia` folder got you back to the release version.

You can check the status of your packages with the `Pkg.status` function. So for example

```
julia> Pkg.status("DataFrames")
  - DataFrames                    0.8.4
```

If any package has its master version installed, that will be specified in the result.

```
julia> Pkg.status("JavaCall")
  - JavaCall                      0.4.2+             master
```

The function without any parameters `Pkg.status()` will show the status for all packages.